# filter a dataframe with many conditions R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a large dataframe (named P) with productnumbers and i want to filter the dataframe with another dataframe (named Numb) of numbers.

```
Productnumb Price Store 
1000           2     A
1001           9     D
1002           1     B
1003           3     A
...
9999           8     D
```

The numb dataframe could also be a list. numb Dataframe below:

```
Good_products
1003
1009
...
9999
```

Expected output

```
Good_products Price Store
1003             3   A
1009            11   G
...
9999             8   D
```

i tried  `P <- P %>% filter(Productnumb == Numb$Good_products)`
I know it is working for 1 or 2 conditions but i have to filter on a lot of conditions, so is there a possibility to filter on large list/dataframes of numbers (as condition)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`semi_join` might be a quick and easy way to "filter" by a list of good products:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Some simulated data
P <- tibble(
  ProductNum = 1000:1999,
  Price = sample(1:20, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  Store = sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

# A sample of "good products"
Numb <- tibble(GoodProducts = sample(P$ProductNum, 400))


P %>% 
  semi_join(Numb, by = c("ProductNum" = "GoodProducts"))

#> # A tibble: 400 x 3
#>    ProductNum Price Store
#>         <int> <int> <chr>
#>  1       1001    14 H    
#>  2       1004     9 Q    
#>  3       1008     6 B    
#>  4       1014    17 Z    
#>  5       1018    18 Q    
#>  6       1020     3 P    
#>  7       1026    14 G    
#>  8       1031    16 L    
#>  9       1034     2 W    
#> 10       1037    14 P    
#> # ... with 390 more rows
```

Other steps will sort of depend on how you want to filter. You can pipe a filter (such as `Price < 10`) as a next step, or do further `semi_join`s. This admittedly is just another way of doing what you had noted above so not sure if it solves your problem. Adding lots of conditions to `filter` should work fine as well.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You might also want to try `semi_join` which in this case provides the exact same outcome. Contrary to `inner_join` the function  `semi_join` will in general only filter the data, but will not join additional columns

Comment: that's indeed the one I had meant to go for, but seem to have got a little mixed up! Will correct - thanks @Cettt!